# Keycloak SSO url custom issue

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, okta, google-workspace, idp

I want to set up keycloak as IDP of the SSO integrated with Google workspace. The sso login and logout urls look like "https://IP address:8443/auth/realms/demo/protocol/saml", but I found other people uses https://sso.domain.com instead.

I searched many documents in the internet, but still didn't figure out how to achieve this, does anyone know how to custmize the sso url with my own domain? Your replies will be much appreciated.

I don't know if this can be done by adding cname records for domain.com, but seems this is not the way.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use a web server like nginx or apache to proxy the traffic from the clients hitting a https://sso.domain.com address to the actual keycloak server.  Search for nginx proxy for keycloak.